# Allowing binary in the same crate to use library's modules but disallowing external crates to use the same modules

Tags: rust, module, visibility

I have three files under the `src` directory:

```
src
|____ keys.rs // a 'sub-module' under `lib.rs`
|____ lib.rs
|____ main.rs // binary file
```

In my `cargo.toml`, I specify specifically the paths to the `lib` and `bin`, i.e.:

```
[lib]
name = "lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "urs" // name of my binary
path = "src/main.rs"
```

In `keys.rs`, I defined several structs and functions.

In `lib.rs`, I declare `mod keys;`, i.e.:

```
pub(crate) mod keys;

use [...]
```

In `main.rs`, I want to use the module `keys` from `lib`, so I do:

```
use lib::keys;

use [...]
```

I want to expose the module `keys` to be used anywhere within the crate but disallow its use outside of it, hence, I use the visibility modifier `pub(crate)` when declaring `pub(crate) mod keys;` in `lib.rs`.

However, cargo is telling me this:

```
error[E0603]: module `keys` is private
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 | use lib::keys;
  |          ^^^^ private module
  |
note: the module `keys` is defined here
 --> F:\rust_projects\sui-utils-rust\src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | pub(crate) mod keys;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My questions:

Is it possible to achieve what I intend to achieve? I.e. by declaring `pub mod keys;` I'll be allowing external crates to use stuff within the `keys` module, how can I prevent that while retaining crate-exclusive access to the `keys` module?

Comment: When you have a library and one or more binaries in the same folder, they are considered to be _different_ crates. I don't know any way to make a module from the library available only for the local binaries.

Comment: However you can make `keys` public, and add `//! #[doc(hidden)]` to the top of `keys.rs` so that at least it won't appear in the docs, which should discourage others from using it. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/what-to-include.html#what-to-exclude

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by changing your project structure like this:

1. Make **keys.rs** a shared module: Instead of making **keys.rs** a submodule of **lib.rs**, you can make it a shared module that both **lib.rs** and **main.rs** can access.
2. Modifying **lib.rs**: Remove the *pub(crate) mod keys*; declaration from **lib.rs**.
3. Modifying **main.rs**: Instead of using *use lib::keys;*, directly reference **keys.rs** as a module.

Here's how you can modify your files:

`src/keys.rs`

```
// Your structs and functions
```

`src/lib.rs`

```
mod keys;
// Rest of your library code
```

`src/main.rs`

```
mod keys;
// Rest of your binary code

fn main() {
    // You can use items from keys here
}
```

This makes the keys module a shared module between your binary and library within the same crate. This way, it's not exposed to external crates, but both your binary and library can use it.